# Using nightwatch.js how can i select dynamically generated item with a dynamically provided value

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, nightwatch.js

I've   got a problem to identify dynamically generated(using JQuery or some script) element present in a list box . I want to select a particular market value which i pass dynamically .
the code i've used so far is

```
browser.useXpath().waitForElementVisible('.//*[@id="NIRPaymentReasonDropDown_1"]', 1000)
```

`browser.useXpath().click('//*[@id="NIRPaymentReasonDropDown_1"]/span[1]/span/span[1]') 
           .click('//*[@id="NIRPaymentReason_1_listbox"]/li[text()="' + pageValues.market + '"]')`

[image]

here pageValues.market is a dynamically provided value.

**Inshort , i want to know how to generate click event on the dynamically generated listbox item with a dynamically provided value.** using nightwatch.js

kindly help me out to solve this problem

Comment: Have you looked into http://nightwatchjs.org/api/switchWindow.html ?

Comment: Thanks @derp that really worked out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several trial and errors , i succeded with this solution to handle the newly opened tabs of the same webpage

```
 browser.windowHandles(function(result) {
                            var authorizePopup = result.value[1];
                            this.waitForElementVisible('#confirmation-modal', 2000)
                            this.switchWindow(authorizePopup);
                            this.assert.containsText(".modal-title", "Payment Details");
                            this.click('#confirm-checkbox')
                                .click('#submit-payment-btn')
                        })
```

I want  a better way to store the inspected elements in page objects for this newly created tab ..can you give me any suggestions or comments

Comment: Not bad, if you are using page objects, I would suggest puting the selectors such as `#confirmation-modal`, `.modal-title` ,etc into the elements section. That way you can name them something meaningful e.g `elements: {
           'paymentDetailTitle': '.modal-title'
}`
`commands: [{ 'confirmPayment' : function(){
                 this.assert.containsText('@paymentDetailTitle', 'Payement Details');
}]`

Comment: huh? didn't you get it working? i'm just making a suggestion on using the page objects based on http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#page-objects